# How to bundle LGPL libraries into commercial Eclipse-based application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, lgpl

I'm going to bundle several LGPL libraries into commercial Eclipse-based application as plug-ins (I generate plug-in from an existing Jar for each library). My application is not LGPL, and it's closed source app. After reading point ([6](http://bquot.com/8ni)) of the LGPL license I've understood that I have either to include source plug-ins for every LGPL library or provide a link to the source code of these libraries (BTW, where these links must be provided, in About dialog?). Am I correct? Is there an example for such an application?

Thanks!

Comment: in which language, is the source code in?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of an example, but yes you are correct. I don't think the LGPL specifies the exact means that the software should be published in. EPL has a similar requirement for publishing the source code if you have modified their stuff, and I have heard that a standard thing for IBM to do for example is have a zip file of the sources available somewhere on their site or with the product distribution.

So long as it's clear where to find the source, I don't think it matters much exactly how you publish it. And if you have not modified the LGPL source, then you can refer to some place where it is published. You only need to actually publish it if you have modified it in some way (or its not published elsewhere).